# Apply/Remove Css on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking "Show/Hide Submit" button the "Submit" button need to be shown and hidden. My code is working but is there a better way of doing it [Javascript part alone]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .displayNone{
        display : none;
    }
    </style>



    <button id="sub" >Submit</button>
    <button id="control">Show/Hide Submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#control").click(function(){
        if($("#sub").attr("class") == "displayNone"){
            $("#sub").attr("class","")
        }
        else{
            $("#sub").attr("class","displayNone")
        }

        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @ShriyaR what have you done?

Comment: @ShriyaR perhaps you missed to read _is there a better way of doing it_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you are not aware of [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) predefined method :) Try the below code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#control").click(function(){
    $("#sub").toggleClass("displayNone");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Rephrase _Hope you are not aware of_

Answer (score 2):

As a possible improvement to @Nofi's answer, you could cache the "#sub" jQuery object in between clicks :) (It saves you having to find the element everytime)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $sub = $('#sub');
    $("#control").click(function(){
       $sub.toggleClass("displayNone");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: If you only need to select it 1 time then using a variable is overkill :P

Comment: @NachoDawg I like to submit my forms 5 times ;D  Nah, seriously, I think it's a good practice, so you may as well...

Comment: Though your approach is fine as toggle can take place multiple times, your choice of words is worse!

Comment: @RayonDabre Ok, will rephrase! English is not my first language after all :P

Comment: Best Practice is context sensitive. A "better" practice would be to use pure js because it's such a short code block

Comment: @NachoDawg Agree with the pure js solution, but a better practice is always a better practice. A "context sensitive better practice" is an optimal solution for that specific context

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to display or hide your `#sub` button:

```
$(function() {
    $("#control").click(function(){
        $("#sub").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

When called without arguments, this method simply displays or hides matched elements, i.e., toggles the elements current visibility state.

Comment: It simply displays or hides matched elements, i.e., toggles the elements current visibility state. Additional options could be used to specify animations and callbacks as well. For more info, please refer to the documentation (hyperlink in my answer)

Comment: I am aware of that but there are many who are not. That would make your answer more useful..

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer to add that information ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .displayNone{
        display : none;
    }
    </style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#control").click(function () {
            $('#sub').toggleClass("displayNone");

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="sub" >Submit</button>
    <button id="control">Show/Hide Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: better to delete this answer, the way you are posted is not acceptable. you can see other answers to learn or take a tour to find how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna offer a solution that is different from literally everyone elses

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $sub = $('#sub');

    $("#control").click(function(){
        $sub.attr("class") == "displayNone" ? 
        $sub.attr("class","") : $sub.attr("class","displayNone")
    })
});
```

Yes you can use `toggle()` or `toggleClass()`, but if there's another point down the line to test whether `#sub` has that class or not then maybe `?:` is a "better" solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` too  [**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/h3pj11Lf/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#control").click(function () {

        if($("#control").hasClass("yoyo"))
        {
         $('#sub').fadeIn(700);
            $("#control").removeClass("yoyo");

        }
        else
        {
        $('#sub').fadeOut(700);
            $("#control").addClass("yoyo");

        }


        });
    });
```